# Select unique record based on column value priority

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

This is a continuation of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913588/select-records-based-on-column-priority).

In the following example:

```
id       PRODUCT ID    COLOUR
1        1001          GREEN
2        1002          GREEN
3        1002          RED
4        1003          RED
```

Given a product ID, I want to retrieve only one record - that with GREEN colour, if one exists, or the RED one otherwise.  It sounds like I need to employ DISTINCT somehow, but I don't know how to supply the priority rule.

Pretty basic I'm sure, but my SQL skills are more than rusty..

**Edit:** Thank you everybody. One more question please: how can this be made to work with multiple records, ie. if the WHERE clause returns more than just one record? The LIMIT 1 would limit across the entire set, while what I'd want would be to limit just within each product.

For example, if I had something like SELECT * FROM table WHERE productID LIKE "1%" ... how can I retrieve each unique product, but still respecting the colour priority (GREEN>RED)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE ProductID = (your id)
ORDER BY colour 
LIMIT 1
```

(Green will come before Red, you see. The LIMIT clause returns only one record)

For your subsequent edit, you can do this

```
select yourtable.*
from
    yourtable
    inner join 
    (select productid, min(colour) mincolour 
    from yourtable
    where productid like '10%'
    group by productid) v
    on yourtable.productid=v.productid
    and yourtable.colour=v.mincolour
```

Comment: See edit above.  Other SQLs have row numbering functions which make this easier, but SQLite lacks that.

Comment: Thanks once again, I never expected it to be this complex!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT top 1 *
FROM <table>
WHERE ProductID = <id>
ORDER BY case when colour ='GREEN' then 1 
              when colour ='RED' then 2 end
```

If you want to order it based on another color, you can give it in the case statement

Comment: Thanks, the case makes it more generic than the other answer, but the top 1 doesn't work in sqlite.