# Select records according to data's priority of a column - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, greatest-n-per-group

## connections_tbl

```
point1   point2   medium

ktm      pkr      air
pkr      ktm      road
pkr      baglung  road
baglung  palpa    road
ktm      brt      air
brt      ktm      road
baglung  pkr      train
```

required output

```
point1   point2   medium

ktm      pkr      air
pkr      baglung  train
baglung  palpa    road
ktm      brt      air
```

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913588/select-records-based-on-column-priority) question.I want to do is create a list of unique rows based on the value of medium, with priority to air,train and road if all medium records exist for the same points. 
Note:Priority order is air>train>road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions `least()` and `greatest()` since points are interchangeable:

```
select t.point1, t.point2, t.medium
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(
      partition by least(point1, point2), greatest(point1, point2) 
      order by field(medium, 'air', 'train', 'road')
    ) rn
    from connections_tbl 
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nktFzyM8i6QP9N2yFxeMhR/5).
Results:

```
| point1  | point2 | medium |
| ------- | ------ | ------ |
| baglung | palpa  | road   |
| baglung | pkr    | train  |
| ktm     | brt    | air    |
| ktm     | pkr    | air    |
```

Comment: your solution is almost correct for us. please check again the modified question. point1 and point 2 values are interchangeable. eg. ktm can be in point1 column or point2 column

Comment: What is your version of MySql

Comment: yessss..finally . Thank you so much for the solution. :) @forpas

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with  correlated subquery:

```
select c.*
from connections_tbl c
where c.medium = (
    select c1.medium 
    from connections_tbl c1
    where c1.point1 = c.point1 and c1.point2 = c.point2
    order by field(medium, 'air', 'train', 'road')
    limit 1
) t
```

Alternatively, in MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select point1, point2, medium
from (
    select 
        c.*,
        row_number() over(partition by point1, point2 order by field(medium, 'air', 'train', 'road')) rn
    from connections_tbl c
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: whats the meaning of t in the first query.

Comment: Both queries do the same thing, which is generate one record per `(point1, point2)` tuple according to the priority rules. The first query uses a correlated subquery that returns the top priority `medium` for each tuple.

Comment: when i write t it gives me an error and if dont write t, it gives output but not the expected output .Gives all the records from the table.

Comment: your second query worked with the pervious question. Thanks for that . Please check once again , i have modified the question , point1 value can be in point2 and viceversa. i.e 
`ktm pkr air`
`pkr ktm road`